# SQL Select Distinct with multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have the following select statement which works fine (using SQL Server 2012) :

```
SELECT distinct(Department) FROM Projects
```

But when I try the following:

```
SELECT 'January', distinct(Department) FROM Projects
```

I get an error message that I could not understand what was next to `(`

I tried the group by as well but did not seem to work:

```
SELECT 'January' mm, distinct(Department)
FROM Projects
GROUP BY mm
```

Comment: But what are you trying to do? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT department, 'January' mm FROM projects
```

One note: You should uppercase SQL keywords.

Comment: Yes; DISTINCT is not a function, so no parentheses.